# Error #1064 SQL when try to convert to VARCHAR with thousand commas

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I got this error:

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar,convert(Money, `donate_amt`),1),'.00','')' at line 1"

when try to convert all the Number of column: donate_amt, table" "corp_donate". Can help me how to fix it. Below is the code I tried:

```
select replace(convert(varchar,convert(Money, `donate_amt`),1),'.00','')
```

Comment: Is money a standard datatype in mysql? why not try converting it to something like Decimal (19,4).

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace(convert(varchar,cast(donate_amt as money),1), '.00','')
```

try this....

Comment: I tried your code but still didn't work :( Still the same error. Btw, I run the SQL script on Xampp/localhost. Not sure if any different from MySQL about the syntax.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format try this link ... this might help u...

Comment: Hi mate, the example only show for 1 number. How do I select and format for all the rows of a column (donate_amt)? Thanks

Comment: CONCAT('$',FORMAT(SUM(`donate_amt`),2)) AS donate_amt  how abt this??